# Why are my Simple Hierarchical Select fields not opening in multifield edit form?

Tags: users, forms, taxonomy-terms

My User Registration form has a multi field. In the sub fields, I have used term references as simple hierarchical select. As I need adding new value option as well. Data is added through these fields.

But when a user navigates to its edit profile page, these select fields are not shown.

Any suggestions about what is missing or wrong?